# How to permit nested hash parameters with the StrongParameters gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, strong-parameters

I am using Ruby on Rails 4.1 and I would like to permit the following incoming parameters by using the [StrongParameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) gem:

```
# Parameters:
{
  "my_key" => {
    "one"  => {
      "0"  => { "a" => "a_value", "b" => "b_value"},
      "1"  => { "a" => "a_value", "b" => "b_value"},
      "2"  => { "a" => "a_value", "b" => "b_value"}
    },
    "two"  => {
      "0"  => { "c" => "c_value", "d" => "d_value"},
      "1"  => { "c" => "c_value", "d" => "d_value"},
      "2"  => { "c" => "c_value", "d" => "d_value"}
    }
  }
}
```

In controller I tried

```
params
  .require(:my_key)
  .permit(
    [
      :one  => [
        "0" => [:a, :b],
        "1" => [:a, :b],
        "2" => [:a, :b]
      ],
      :two  => [
        "0" => [:c, :d],
        "1" => [:c, :d],
        "2" => [:c, :d]
      ]
    ]
  )
```

and

```
params
  .require(:my_key)
  .permit(
    {
      :one  => {
        "0" => [:a, :b],
        "1" => [:a, :b],
        "2" => [:a, :b]
      },
      :two  => {
        "0" => [:c, :d],
        "1" => [:c, :d],
        "2" => [:c, :d]
      }
    }
  )
```

But I get the error

```
ActionController::UnpermittedParameters (found unpermitted parameters: a, b)
```

How above parameters should be permitted?

Comment: Btw, this gem that you mentioned is NOT compatible with Rails 4.0+. It's only for versions before that.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you need to do:

1. Remove Strong Parameters gem from your `Gemfile`.
2. Use this in the controller.

`params.require(:my_key).permit({:one=>[:a, :b],:two=>[:c, :d]})`

I think this has something to do with how nested attributes work. The ids `"0", "1", "2"` etc are implicit.

You can test in the console like this:

```
$ bin/rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.2)
2.1.0 :001 > params = ActionController::Parameters.new "my_key"=>{"one"=>{"0"=>{"a"=>"a_value","b"=>"b_value"},"1"=>{"a"=>"a_value","b"=>"b_value"},"2"=>{"a"=>"a_value","b"=>"b_value"}},"two"=>{"0"=>{"c"=>"c_value","d"=>"d_value"},"1"=>{"c"=>"c_value","d"=>"d_value"},"2"=>{"c"=>"c_value","d"=>"d_value"}}}
 => {"my_key"=>{"one"=>{"0"=>{"a"=>"a_value", "b"=>"b_value"}, "1"=>{"a"=>"a_value", "b"=>"b_value"}, "2"=>{"a"=>"a_value", "b"=>"b_value"}}, "two"=>{"0"=>{"c"=>"c_value", "d"=>"d_value"}, "1"=>{"c"=>"c_value", "d"=>"d_value"}, "2"=>{"c"=>"c_value", "d"=>"d_value"}}}} 
2.1.0 :002 > p = params.require(:my_key).permit({:one=>[:a, :b],:two=>[:c, :d]})
 => {"one"=>{"0"=>{"a"=>"a_value", "b"=>"b_value"}, "1"=>{"a"=>"a_value", "b"=>"b_value"}, "2"=>{"a"=>"a_value", "b"=>"b_value"}}, "two"=>{"0"=>{"c"=>"c_value", "d"=>"d_value"}, "1"=>{"c"=>"c_value", "d"=>"d_value"}, "2"=>{"c"=>"c_value", "d"=>"d_value"}}} 
2.1.0 :003 >
```